# How to Git control code from a remote computer?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have the following situation:

1. I have a remote workstation (WS_A) in which I have code written. I write and execute the code in this workstation
2. I access WS_A through SSH from my local Linux computer (loc_m). I also use Visual Studio code remote extension to directly code the code in the workstation. I transfer files from and to the WS_A using `scp`
3. The worskation WS_A *does not* have access to the internet.

So I would like to do the following:

1. Git manage my code: Simple enough, Git is installed in the workstation so no problem
2. Keep a repository of this code in my local machine loc_m
3. Keep a repository of this code in GitLab (or GitHub alternatively)

How can I do 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3):

> The worskation WS_A does not have access to the internet.

But you have SSH access to it, which means it does have access to the internet, ...provided you set up a [reverse SSH tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490641/7490).

- If `loc_m` is Windows, install [`px`](https://github.com/genotrance/px) in order to set your `HTTP(S)_PROXY` to localhost:3128
- if `loc_m` is Linux, install a [proxy like squid](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490641/7490), again to set an `HTTP_PROXY` to localhost:3128.

Then, from `loc_m:`

```
ssh -R 3120:127.0.0.1:3128 -fNT -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey WS_A
```

With `WS_A` an entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host WS_A
  hostname ws.A.hostname
  User rmeoteUser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_for_WS_A
```

On `WS_A`, set HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY to localhost:3120: that port will be redirected to your local machine, port 3128, which in turn has internet access.

From there, your remote code can be directly committed and pushed to GitHub/GitLab. No more `scp` back and forth.